# ArcGIS Online map viewer labeling not working

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-online

Export dynamicLayers with custom label not working,
please see my screen shot.

[image]

Here is my ArcGIS server https://gis.la-quinta.org/arcgis/rest/services

I have 2 working example and the other 90% of MapServer label not working.

The working example is here:

https://gis.la-quinta.org/arcgis/rest/services/GoGov/map_base_test/MapServer

https://gis.la-quinta.org/arcgis/rest/services/TrackIt/TRACKiT_Data/MapServer

Other then this, all failed on custom labeling.

follow the instruction on my screenshot to open ArcGIS Online map viewer,

[image]

[image]

[image]

My finding is:
[image]

[image]

Comment: So, it's not AGOL which is faulty, but your own Server host? That's not what the Question title asserts. Please [edit] the Question to specify the exact release of Server installed locally.  This may be an Esri Tech Support issue.

Comment: AGOL and AGOL-map-viewer is two total different things.  My title  is correct, My title does not refer to AGOL.  My topic have nothing to do with AGOL.  My topic use AGOL-map-viewer, which you can open it by click button link on my arcgis server rest api endpoint page.

Answer (score -1):

I have called ESRI customer service,  they did not fixed it.
They don't know what to do, eventually I found solution on my own !!!

Here is my post on esri community

[https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-enterprise-questions/arcgis-online-map-viewer-failed-to-create-label/m-p/1213682](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehuwk.png)

The solution is turn on maplex labeling engine in arcmap.

How to do that?

Use Maplex engine fixed my problem.
If you use standard labeling engine, later on, when you publish it to arcgis server,
you  can not create custom labeling with arcgis online map viewer.

By using Maplex engine, you can create custom labeling with arcgis online map viewer.

As Mattropolis suggested, here is how I turn on Maplex engine on my arcmap and on my arcPro.

Arcmap First:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is esri document

Enabling the Maplex Label Engine and adding the Labeling toolbar

https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/enabling-maplex-for-arcgis-and-adding-the-labeling-toolbar.htm

How to turn on maplex at ArcPro

[image]

Warning:

Analyze does not identify the compatible issue !!!! Which it should.  Maybe is a bug need improvement.

ESRI never tell us that standard label engine will not compatible with arcgis online map viewer. You have to figure out on your own.

I have called esri customer service, they create a case with case number, however, they don't know what is wrong, don't know what to do, eventually they said they will escalate it to higher level team for further investigation.

[image]